# Trying to change a timer once a button is pressed

Tags: vb.net

I have a check going every 60 seconds, if the alarm is true it will open form2 play a song etc.

but the button on form2 should set the waittimer = 180000 which should make the next check occur half an half an hour later.

I'm not used to using timers, what am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class Form1
Public Property waittimer As Integer
Public Property playsong As Boolean = True
Private WithEvents Tmr As New Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName).Length > 1) Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
    Tmr.Enabled = False
    Tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
    playsong = False
    Try


        ' Create a request for the URL. 
        Dim request As WebRequest = _
          WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/example.aspx")
        ' If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        ' Get the response.
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        ' Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()

        Dim responseArray() As String
        responseArray = Split(responseFromServer, "|")

        Dim D As New Data
        D.maxcalls = responseArray(0)
        D.cph = responseArray(1)
        D.mht = responseArray(2)
        D.alarm = responseArray(3)
        Form2.startsong(D)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    playsong = True
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Try
        If waittimer = 180000 Then
            Tmr.Interval = waittimer
            Tmr.Start()
            waittimer = 60000
        Else
            waittimer = 60000
        End If

        ' Create a request for the URL. 
        Dim request As WebRequest = _
          WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/example.aspx")
        ' If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        ' Get the response.
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        ' Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()

        Dim responseArray() As String
        responseArray = Split(responseFromServer, "|")

        Dim D As New Data
        D.maxcalls = responseArray(0)
        D.cph = responseArray(1)
        D.mht = responseArray(2)
        D.alarm = responseArray(3)
        D.forcealarm = False
        e.Result = D
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim D As New Data
        D.maxcalls = 404
        D.cph = 404
        D.mht = 404
        D.alarm = True
        D.forcealarm = True
        e.Result = D
    End Try

    Tmr.Interval = waittimer
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If Not IsNothing(e.Result) Then
        Dim strtime As String
        Dim englandtime = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC"))
        strtime = DatePart(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Hour, englandtime) & DatePart(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Minute, englandtime)

        Dim D As Data = DirectCast(e.Result, Data)
        If D.forcealarm = True Then
            Form2.startsong(D)
        End If
        If D.alarm Then
            If strtime < 730 And strtime > 0 Then

            Else
                Form2.startsong(D)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Tmr.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
    Tmr.Stop()
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Data
Public Property maxcalls As Integer
Public Property cph As Integer
Public Property mht As Integer
Public Property alarm As Boolean
Public Property forcealarm As Boolean
End Class
```

Form2

```
Public Class Form2
Public audio As New AudioFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Help.mp3")
Public Sub startsong(ByVal D As Data)
    Me.Show()
    MHTvalue.Text = D.mht.ToString
    Maxcallsvalue.Text = D.maxcalls
    CPHvalue.Text = D.cph
    If Form1.playsong = True Then
        audio.Play()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Me.Close()
    audio.Stop()
    Form1.waittimer = 180000
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    audio.Stop()
    Form1.waittimer = 180000
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Minimize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    audio.Stop()
    Form1.waittimer = 180000
End Sub
```

Comment: What is it "not" doing? From a quick browse through your code, it looks like you are trying to set the timer on form1, from form2, while your form1 you use, is not the instance of the original form1 instance?

Comment: I'm trying to change the timer which is used for getting the results from 60 seconds to half an hour.

form1 is just sat in the notification tray

Comment: I see no code in form2 that actually gets the running instance of form1? Simply referencing form1 like that references a blank copy of form1, not the instance of form1already running.

Comment: Again, If you share where it is behaving differently than what you expect it to do, it will be easier to help.

Comment: instead of waiting 30 minutes it gets the results after 60 seconds and starts to play the song again.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder "Simply referencing form1 like that references a blank copy of form1, not the instance of form1already running."  Not necessarily true.  If Form1 is the "Startup Object" then using `Form1` will get the "default instance", which is in fact the one that is running.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder See [My.Forms Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/87y2hdsf.aspx): "You can access the forms provided by the My.Forms object by using the name of the form, without qualification. Because the property name is the same as the form's type name, this allows you to access a form as if it had a default instance. For example, My.Forms.Form1.Show is equivalent to Form1.Show."

Comment: @Idle_Mind , k, I get that... but in this case, an instance of form1 was created. In my experience, I have had to psychically go and look through the loaded instances. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because your timer on the original form1 instance never get re configured by your code. You are instead setting a timer on a new copy of form 1 that is not running (showing).

You need to get the running instance of form1 that you originally opened. A technique I use for something like this, is to tag my form I will be looking for, and then stepping through the form instances currently running, getting my form via its tag, setting that found form equal to the object I am working with, and THEN use the properties/methods of that form.

Set your form1's tag to "myTag".

Then on form 2:

```
        For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms

            If Not f.InvokeRequired Then
                'Can access the form directly.

                If f.Tag = "myTag" Then
                    'this is my form
                    Dim fcast As New form1
                    fcast = f
                    fcast.<---- use your methods / properties...
                End If

            End If

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
Public Property waittimer As Integer
```

To:

```
Public Property waittimer As Integer
    Get
        Return Tmr.Interval
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value > 0 Then
            Tmr.Interval = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

You were changing the waittimer value, but not the actual Interval() of the Timer as well.  This links the two together.